# Is there a Galactic Civil War map?

Tags: star-wars

Is there a map showing what areas of the galaxy the Empire and the Rebellion controlled during the time of the Galactic Civil War?

Comment: The question has a pretty big flaw, in that the Rebellion didn't really control worlds.

Comment: I've voted to close because the question demonstrates a fundamental flaw (in that the Rebellion existed ***within*** the Empire). As such any answer is essentially meaningless in the same way that it would be pointless to ask for a map that shows where America starts and Idaho stops.

Comment: @Valorum still, a rebel group *can* hold territory in a de facto sense. Just look at Syria, with several factions each exercising some level of practical control over areas that are all *de jure* all sovereign Syrian territory. There are even maps that have been made that approximate what areas are under control of which factions.

Comment: @Valorum I seem to remember a lot of maps showing which territory wash held by US forces and which by Rebel forces during various dates in the US Civil War.  Like this one:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Civil_War#/media/File:Civil_war_1861-1865.png

Comment: @M.A.Golding - Sure, but those were de-facto controlled by a different side.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, throughout the Civil War, the Alliance for the Restoration of the Republic really controlled one world: Mon Calamari, the homeworld of the Mon Calamaris and the Quarrens.

Everything else, including the GHQ on Yavin and Hoth, was always treated as being temporary accommodations, given that the Empire was relentlessly pursuing them.

Comment: They asked for a map, which you did not deliver

Comment: @Mr.DancingMan Petty reaction on your part. Also, see Valorum's comment on the question above: any map would be meaningless.

Comment: I think this is a good interpretation of the question.